# webview with configurable URL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview, nsapplication

I am new to objective c programming and working with cocoa application.

Here is my `static URL` webview based application.

**AppDelegate.h contains**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webview;

@end
```

**And my AppDelegate.m contains**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize webview;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
    [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];

}

@end
```

It is working fine with this specified `URL`.

I am trying to find out solution which make me able to configure URL.
e.g save URL from separate window and load my webview with new specified URL by hitting on Save button.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please add more description, about how you will configure and save URL.

Comment: Right now when i run my application it shows me webview with specified URL. ok. e.g i have setting option in menu where it should make me able to change url etc.

Comment: This menu exists at your application level or website level? If it is at application level then as Eli has suggest is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `UITextField` and a `UIButton`. Upon a button click, load the url that was inserted into the text field.
For example, lets assume your text field is called _tf and your webview is called _wv:

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked
{
    [_wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_tf.text]]];
}
```

Of course you need to validate that the entered text is actually a valid URL.

Comment: My both windows are on same .xib file. when i run application it gives me my webview window with specified URL. Right. Now i have menu where i have an option "setting" it shows me 2nd window on which i have text field ( for URL ) and a save button. I dont know how to connect save button with my webview window that when i click on save button it should refresh with newly given URL.

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot of code to write here how to do this.

At first look at this tutorial: It will give you a specified explanation how to make a good webView: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoynCQLF2H0

After that you need to have 2 views. How to do this: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL13RmE18ek

Then you need to make the outlets for the UITextField and UIButton and you need to make an IBAction for the button.

After that you can use NSUserDefaults to save data and retrieve it in another view:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0d1E3S-PKE

As you can see, everything that you want to know is on Youtube. Look at some great tutors like: Dani Arnaout, GeekyLemonDevelopment or TheNewBoston.